# Error starting Strapi app, Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to set up a strapi app.

Ive installed the app with `yarn create strapi-app app-name`

if I then try start the app with `yarn develop`

I get the error

`Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) { errno: -54, code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }`

Anyone know what this is ore how to fix it